# How to have split-screen displayed applications all in full-screen mode?

Tags: windows, split-window

I am using a surface pro and I would like to have two applications in split-screen mode, for example, VScode on the left and OneNote on the right. Without an extended monitor, every inch of the display matters, and it would be so great if I can have both of them in the full-screen mode that way both applications could maximize the display area (more vertical space with title bar and file menu bar hidden, more horizontal space with scroll bar hidden)

I am wondering if there is any approach/application to make this happen?

Comment: Perhaps you described this in detail but I am still not understanding.  What do you expect from "full screen mode"?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas More description added, thanks!

Comment: In other words, you want the apps *think* they're going fullscreen?

Comment: @user1686 something like that, to make them into fullscreen mode while only occupy part of the display